# Using std::filesystem::path to convert between separator types

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm working on code that involves loading a file from a path which is constructed as a concatenation of a given "base" path and a secondary relative path, loaded from another file. For example (and where I'm running into an issue), the base path is "assets/models/", and the secondary path is "maps\map.png".
Straight concatenation of these two strings gives "assets/models/maps\map.png". When running on POSIX systems this fails to load. Up to now I've been sorting this out by just replacing the backslashes with forward slashes with

`std::replace( path.begin(), path.end(), '\\', '/' );`

but I'd like to use C++17's `std::filesystem::path` to do this instead.

The description of `std::filesystem::path::make_preferred()` suggests that it should replace the separators:

> "Converts all directory separators in the generic-format view of the path to the preferred directory separator.
>   For example, on Windows, where \ is the preferred separator, the path foo/bar will be converted to foo\bar"

When implemented in the code, however, it doesn't convert anything. I've also verified that std::filesystem::path::preferred_separator is as expected - '/'.

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `make_preferred()`? Or am I just using it wrong?

Here's a cut down version of the code that doesn't work (this isn't the implemented code, but is close enough to it):

```
const char * loadedPath = "maps\\map.png"
std::string loadedPathStr = std::string( loadedPath );
auto wPath = std::filesystem::path( loadedPathStr );
wPath = wPath.make_preferred();

basePath = std::filesystem::path( "./a/b/" );
auto totalPath = basePath / wPath;
auto wStr = totalPath.generic_string();
std::cout << wStr << std::endl;
```

This outputs "./a/b/maps\\map.png"

When debugging the implemented code, it looks like `wPath` is optimised out; there's no way of inspecting it.

Strangely, when I compile and run this standalone test program, it works as expected:

```
int main(){
   assert( std::filesystem::path::preferred_separator == '/' );            
   const char * cPath = "maps\\map.png";
   std::string path = std::string( cPath );
   auto wPath = std::filesystem::path( path );
   wPath = wPath.make_preferred();
   std::string wStr = wPath.generic_string();
   std::cout << wStr << std::endl;
}
```

<s>This outputs "maps/map.png".</s> I can't read. This also outputs the incorrect value.

Anyone know whats going on here?

EDIT:
<s>Tried compiling with clang (using gcc before), and it works as expected (separator is converted).</s> Ignore this, made a mistake in recompiling.

I'm running this on Linux, and the path exists.

Comment: Are you on a POSIX platform, or Windows?  If POSIX, do you have a file named `maps\map.png` in the `assets` subdirectory `models`?

Comment: What is your toolchain?

Comment: Please present non-working code in MCVE form, like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db69eb955e36f255).

Comment: The problem may be:  on Windows `\ ` and `/ ` are both path separators, and the `\ ` is the preferred one.  On POSIX, `/ ` is a path separator, while `\ ` is not a path separator, so make_preferred won't convert `\ ` (which is just a valid, normal filename character).

Comment: BTW, `make_preferred` and `generic_string` both basically do the same thing, so you shouldn't be using both of them. `make_preferred` is for when you want the path's internally stored string to use the generic separator. `generic_string` is for when you want a *copy* of the path string in the generic format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `make_preferred()`?

Not entirely, but subtly yes. A directory separator (in the generic format) is either the preferred separator, or the fallback separator: `/`. On systems where the preferred separator is `/` (e.g. POSIX), directory separator is only `/`. On such systems `make_preferred` doesn't modify the path, which explains why it would be optimised out completely.

The simplest way to replace back slashes with forward slashes is `std::replace`. However, do note that back slashes are valid characters in file names in POSIX, so such conversion may break the use of file names that use it.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for explaining it. It's unfortunate that the path system won't do the conversion but practically it makes sense that it won't since the backslash is a valid filename character.

Comment: Just as a further question here, why does the standalone version work?

Comment: Seems I can't read my own terminal. Rechecked there and you're correct, it doesn't work. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write cross-platform code with `filesystem`, you should try to stick with the generic format. The behavior of all other formats of filesystem strings is implementation-dependent.

An implementation that allows alternative directory separators will treat them as directory separators. But other, perfectly valid, implementations that don't recognize those separators will not recognize them. "/" is always a directory separator; whether "\" is a separator or not depends on the implementation.

`make_preferred` converts from the implementation's path format into the generic format. As such, it's behavior is implementation-dependent.

The main reason behind dealing in non-generic formats is when you're getting path strings from the native OS API. Such path strings will likely be in the implementation's format, so `path` needs to be able to recognize them and work with them. For string literals built into your program, you should always prefer the generic format (unless your application is OS-specific, or you are selecting different strings based on the OS your code is being used on).

Comment: Ideally I would stick with the generic format for all the string literals, but unfortunately I'm dealing with loading 3D model files which have baked filepaths where I have little-to-no control over the format. Thanks for the response though, between this and the others I see my misunderstanding of the make_preferred() function (and the overall treatment of separators)